# wcf webservice not running

Tags: wcf

I m trying to create a wcf service

but it keep bugging me with the below error while running

HTTP could not register URL http://+:80/ConsoleWCFapp/. Your process does not have access rights to this namespace (see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=70353 for details).

code

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
   ServiceHost host = new ServiceHost(typeof(StockService), new Uri("http://localhost:8000/ConsoleWCFapp"));
   host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IStockService), new BasicHttpBinding(), "");
   host.Open();

   Console.WriteLine("Listening to request now, Please enter to exit \n\n");
   Console.ReadLine();

   host.Close();
}
```

please advice

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Run the code / Visual Studio as Administrator.  I just ran into the same thing in my environment.

Answer (score 0):

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ServiceHost host = new ServiceHost(typeof(StockService));
        host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IStockService), new BasicHttpBinding(), "http://localhost:8000/ConsoleWCFapp");
        host.Open();
        Console.WriteLine("Listening to request now, Please enter to exit \n\n");
        Console.ReadLine();
        host.Close();
        }
```

try it